# Show that there is a nonabelian group of order $p^n$ with a cyclic subgroup of index $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

Assume $p$ is a prime integer and let $n$ be an integer such that $n \geq 3$.

> Show that there is a nonabelian group of order $p^n$ with a cyclic subgroup of index $p$.

Comment: Are you familiar with: A) semi-direct products, B) the automorphisms of $C_{P^{n-1}}$, C) how to combine those two?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm familiar with both but really not good at either. These two are my weakest...

Comment: Ok. Let's do $p=n=3$ as an example. Let $H=\langle c \rangle$ be cyclic of order nine. Because $\gcd(4,9)=1$ the mapping $\phi:H\to H, c\mapsto c^4$ can be extended to an automorphism. It is not hard to show that $\phi$ has order three. That is $\phi(\phi(\phi(h)))=h$ for all $h\in H$. Then you can form the semidirect product
$$G=H\rtimes C_3,$$ where conjugation by a generator, call it $a$ of the factor $C_3$ amounts to applying $\phi$. Or, $G$ is the group generated by $c$ and $a$ such that $ c^6=1, a^3=1$ and
$$aha^{-1}=\phi(h)=h^4$$ for all $h\in\langle C\rangle$.

Comment: Does that make sense to you? Can you figure out what changes you need to make to this construction to get the general one?

Comment: Why do we need to care about the integer 4 in $gcd(4,9)=1$?

Comment: To have $\phi$ extended to an automorphism, we can pick any number (for example 4) as long as 9 is coprime with it, right?

Comment: Correct. A key reason why I used $4$ is that $4^3\equiv1\pmod 9$. This, in turn gives the relation $\phi(\phi(\phi(c)))=c$. We need that to form a non-commutative semidirect product $C_6\rtimes C_3$. Cannot use $1$ because then the semidirect product would be direct (and abelian). Cannot use $2$, because $2^3\not\equiv1\pmod9$. Could have used $7$ instead.

Comment: Hi @JyrkiLahtonen, i wonder, in general, how do we show that we can arrange things such that the order of $\phi$ divides the order of $a$? I know in your construction these two orders are both 3 so it works but is there a general argument that tells us this is always possible?

Comment: @mkmlp The available orders of $\phi$ depend on the automorphism group of $H$. Here it is known that $Aut(H)\simeq C_{(p-1)p^{n-1}}$ because $H\simeq C_{p^n}$. If $H$ is cyclic of order $m$, then $Aut(H)\simeq \Bbb{Z}_m^*$ and it is already a bit more complicated. For starters, this group is usually not cyclic. Anyway, for the semidirect product $H\rtimes C_\ell$ to exist, it is enough that the order of $a$ is a multiple of the order of $\phi$. We need the mapping $a^i\mapsto \phi^i$ to be a homomorphism of $C_\ell\to Aut(H)$. Look up semi-direct products.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks a lot for answering! My confusion is exactly why we can always choose a $\phi$ s.t. $|\phi| \mid |a|$, i.e., why such a $\phi\in\text{Aut}(H)$ always exists. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @mkmlp It doesn't always exist. Well, we always have the choice $\phi=id_H$, an automorphism of order $1$, but then the semi-direct product $H\rtimes\langle a\rangle$ is a direct product. For example, there is no non-abelian semi-direct product  $C_5\rtimes C_3$ because $Aut(C_5)\simeq C_4$ has no elements of order three. On the other hand, the automorphism $\phi: c\mapsto c^{1+p^{n-1}}$ of $C_{p^n}=\langle c\rangle$ is of order $p$. That is because $1+p^{n-1}$ has order $p$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{p^n}^*$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah, I see! Thanks a lot for the detailed explanations!

Answer (score -1):

The dihedral group $D_8$ is of order $8=2^3$ and it is non-abelian group. Also, any subgroup of $D_8$ with order $2$ is cyclic.

Comment: Presumably an answer does not count unless it generates examples for all $n\ge3$ and primes $p$, not just one choice of $n$ and $p$.